# Keep focus() on DOM reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

```
<a id="bigMenu" aria-expanded="false" title="Forschung und Entwicklung" href="index.php?id=4"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" id="spanID"></span>Forschung und Entwicklung</a>
```

I have the following Javascript code that executes when this link is clicked:

```
$('#bigMenu').click(function () {
    element = document.getElementById("spanID");
    menuElement = document.getElementById("bigMenu");
    if (element.className == "glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right") {
        element.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down";
        jQuery("#collapseMenu").show();
        menuElement.setAttribute('aria-expanded', true);
        sessionStorage.setItem("expand", true);
    } else {
        element.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right";
        jQuery("#collapseMenu").hide();
        menuElement.setAttribute('aria-expanded', false);
        sessionStorage.setItem("expand", false);
    }
    curURL = document.URL;
    substring = "id=4";
    if (curURL.match(substring)) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Regarding the curURL bit, I don't want the page to reload if I am already on it. Hence, I just return instead of loading the page (which would be redundant in this case).

What I want to achieve is the following:

- When a user clicks on the F&E link, the page F&E opens (this work) and the focus remains on the F&E link (this does not work).

I tried to achieve it in the following way (additions shown to the above code)

```
jQuery("#collapseMenu").show();
$( document ).ready(function() { menuElement.focus() });
```

That didn't work, so obviously it was not the correct way of going about it. Could someone tell me what would be the correct way of keeping focus here?

Comment: `menuElement` is set but in your click handler but this state is obviously lost when reloading. You should be fine using the id of the menuElement though: `$( document ).ready(function() { $("#bigMenu").focus() });`.

Comment: @collapsar: No, I had tried that earlier. Doesn't work, gives me the same result.